# Sybase - Get names of procs calling a given proc

Tags: stored-procedures, sybase

I am looking for a functionality in reverse to `sp_depends`. `sp_depends` gives names of objects that the current object is using.

I want to get info in a reverse manner i.e. what all objects(procs in my case) calls the given proc ?

#### Note

I am using Sybase 12.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it will help you:

```
declare @Proc varchar(30)

select @Proc='ProcName'

select sod.name 
from sysobjects so
join sysdepends sd  on sd.id = so.id
join sysobjects sod on sod.id = sd.depid
where so.name = @Proc
and sod.type = 'P'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this query, I fixed the query of the previous answer, It gets the stored procedure(s) than call(s) the given stored procedure:

```
declare @Proc varchar(30)

select @Proc='procedure name'

select so.name
 from sysobjects so
 join sysdepends sd  on sd.id = so.id
 join sysobjects sod on sod.id = sd.depid
 where sod.name = @Proc
 and sod.type = 'P';
```